# How to allow multiple users to commit from same git repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repository which will have two users committing from the same repository on the same machine. I know I can edit the config options for the project to set a user for that particular repository, but is there a way to allow multiple users to commit from the same exact repository (perhaps by specifying username in the commit)?

Comment: `git commit --author="Foo <foo@example.com>"`, but why would you want to have different people work on the same repository?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git